# In Bleach, if a Shinigami transfers their power to a human, where does their zanpakuto come from?

Tags: bleach

So, at the beginning of Bleach Rukia attempts to transfer her power to Ichigo but he ends up taking all of them. My question is, say that worked exactly how Rukia thought it would, would he have gotten his own Zanpakuto or just borrow hers?

I ask because, in later arcs we're introduced to Oetsu Nimaiya, the creator of the Zanpakuto. And according to him, no Shinigami has ever obtained a zanpakuto before being given a asauchi. This pretty much definitively states that a zanpakuto can't be created solely by a person's soul/spirit energy.

So that raises the question, if Rukia's plan had worked at the start, not to mention the other times it must have been done for her to know she could do it, where would the sword come from?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the sword Ichigo used for most of the series was a Quincy manifestation made by the Old Man? The actual Zangetsu is the dual blades Ichigo wields at the very end. I could be mistaken though.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, since her soul reaper powers would be transferred into Ichigo, he would have her sword, but not its powers. almost like a model of the sword, it's not actually her all-white sword, but an asuchi. as stated by LavenderTGhost, Zangetsu was actually a manifestation of his Quincy powers, and his actual sword was forged by Oetsu Nimaiya. the reason it consists of two swords is that one sword is his Quincy powers while the other is his soul reaper powers. second off, Rukia's plan failed. straight up flopped. Rukia planned on giving him only a little of her powers so that he could protect his family but ended up giving him all of them because the hogyocu was near